# Connect a web form to MySQL database

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server, forms

Using a MySQL database, I add users to the database like this test data:

```
INSERT INTO `database_users`.`Members` (`ID`, `Username`, `Password`,
 `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Email Address`, `Telephone Number`,
 `Address Line 1`, `Address Line 2`, `Town/City`, `Postcode`,
 `Mailing-list`, `Terms`) VALUES (NULL, 'Test', '', '', '', '', '', '',
 NULL, '', '', NULL, '');"
```

My HTML form looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Join!">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Town/City" id="Town/City">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Postcode" id="Postcode">
    </div>
</input>
```

I am looking to submit the form on my website and have the data upload to my MySQL database. Can anyone advise on what I am missing from my form?

Comment: Start from a working example that shows you step by step what to do... You can find many tutorials online.

Comment: How have you connected your php and sql database?

Comment: Yes I have connected my php and sql database using a php template that I found online (the one that asks for database name and password etc). I am just looking for someone to put into Lehman terms what to add to my form (I.e. Where to add my database IDs in <form>)

Comment: just do a google search for sign up and registration in PHP with source code. You will get a lot of results and solid materials including the source code for free

Comment: you need to search online before coming here. Stackoverflow should be your last resort when you have tried everything within your power including searching online.

Comment: I have searched online, as explained in the question, but have become even more confused. The problem with the articles online is that they don't explain why you are doing what you are doing. I just wanted someone to briefly explain what needs to go where, so that I can do it properly. I wouldn't be asking if I wasn't tearing my hair out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sql query seems to be good, but if you don't know how to use PHP you'll be blocked often.

The best thing to do is learn basic PHP to know how to implemant youself your register page, and ask on stackoverflow if you have an issue during the development.

http://www.learn-php.org/

And your form isn't correct: You need a `<form>` input and define on it the method (post or get), and the action (the file where the datas goes).

Basically, your code have to be like:

**HTML (form.html)**

```
<form method="POST" action="save.php">
    <input type="text" name="pseudo">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP (save.php)**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['pseudo'])){ // Test if the variable exists
        $pseudo = $_POST['pseudo'];
        // Your SQL query here which save the pseudo. Don't forget to test your variables.
    }
    else {
        echo "pseudo is required";
    }
?>
```

Don't forget to escape your variables and use prepared statements. Else, your site will be many flaws like XSS or SQL injections.

**Some links**

*A prepared statement with Mysqli*

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

*Prevent XSS attacks*

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

*What is a SQL injection?*

http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Thank you so much! That is really helpful! I've just found myself stuck in a rut and that's exactly the type of advice I was looking for. Much appreciated!

Comment: You are welcome! You can upvote my post if you think it's the answer you need :-)

Comment: I tried to do that but don't have enough 'reputation', I'll come back to it as soon as I have enough to do so! 